# How to call an eclipse wizard in batch mode?

Tags: eclipse, batch-processing, wizard

I have a lot of newly created java classes and need to generate getters and setters (for all fields).

There is a nifty wizard that does this, but it takes only one file at a time.

I would like to do something like

```
eclipse --batch --wizardname=makegetters &lt;wizard parameters here&gt; --files &lt;list of files&gt;
```

or, alternatively, have a wizard that calls other wizards to achieve the above.

Is there something that I can uses or do I have to use external tools (one for each wizard)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for this. Eclipse wizards expect to display a dialog and get responses from that, they do not provide a way to bypass the dialog.

Comment: What a pity, but I'm afraid your statement is true. So I'll have to recode the functionality of the wizards I *really* need with external code.